# inconsistent state and display in React when using browser 'back' button

Tags: reactjs, turbolinks

I am using React 16.1.1 (with the react-rails gem) in a Rails 5.1 app.

The React components on a specific page work fine, except when going back to this page with the browser 'back' button (tested with firefox / chrome / safari). In that case, the display is inconsistent with the state of the component. I've setup a **demo of the problem**: https://lit-bastion-28654.herokuapp.com/.

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. be on /page1
2. click the 'selection mode' button, it sets 'selectionMode' to true
3. click 'page 2'
4. use 'back' button to go back to page 1
5. EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR: the button is grey (selectionMode is reset to false when component loaded). OBSERVED BEHAVIOUR: the button is still blue?!

There, you can see that the button is blue, as if `selectionMode` was true, but the react browser plugin shows that `selectionMode` is false. The React browser plugin shows false information: it shows that the button does not have the 'btn-primary' class (which is normal if selectionMode is false), but you can obviously see that in the DOM, it has the 'btn-primary' class, since it is appears blue.

This is my code:

**page1.html.erb**:

```
<%= react_component("EditableCardList", { editable: true }) %>
```

**editable_card_list.js.jsx**:

```js
class EditableCardList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectionMode: false
    };

    this.toggleSelectionMode = this.toggleSelectionMode.bind(this);
  }


  toggleSelectionMode() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ selectionMode: !prevState.selectionMode }));
  }


  render() {
    if (this.props.editable === true)
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="row card-buttons">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="pull-left">
                <ManageCardsButtons
                  selectionMode={this.state.selectionMode}
                  toggleSelectionMode={this.toggleSelectionMode}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

**manage_cards_buttons.js.jsx**:

```js
class ManageCardsButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <button type="button" className={`btn btn-default btn-sm ${this.props.selectionMode ? 'btn-primary' : ''}`}  onClick={this.props.toggleSelectionMode}>Selection mode</button>

        { this.props.selectionMode && <span>selection mode</span> }
      </span>
    )
  }
}
```

So my question is: **How to make sure that, after using 'back' in the browser, the button is rerendered properly (and appears grey instead of blue)?**

The issue may be related with [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) and caching, but I've not been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: try [opting out of caching](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#opting-out-of-caching) on the React page by including the `<meta>` tag in the page header.

Comment: @RobertFarley That works, although I'd like to avoid it for performance reasons.

Comment: are you using the most recent versions of turbolink and react-rails gem?

Comment: @RobertFarley Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React and TurboLinks conflict, so my final solution was to disable TurboLinks caching on that specific page.

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to page1, Component rerenders, and sets the default selectionMode which is false in your case.

1. you can use redux.
2. you can save selectionMode to your
   localStorage when it changes, and by default load it from the
   storage.

Comment: You're not answering the problem. I've updated my question to be more precise about what I mean.

Comment: I **do** want selectionMode to be reset to false when the component is rerendered. The problem is that the button does not reflect that state, it is displayed with the 'btn-primary' class when it should not.